# Applying a GPO to one user on one computer only

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I have a GPO that I need to apply to the user `DOMAIN\DumbGuy`, but only when he logs on to `DOMAIN\DumbGuysComputer$`. When `DOMAIN\NiceReceptionist` logs on to `DOMAIN\DumbGuysComputer$` it should not apply. When `DOMAIN\DumbGuy` logs on to `DOMAIN\ReceptionstsComputer$` it should not apply.

It needs to only only apply to **one person** on **one computer**.

If I apply the GPO to the User object, it will apply to all his computers. If I apply the GPO to the Computer object, it will apply to all users on that computer. If I apply it to both, it spreads even wider.

How can I apply a GPO to just one user on just one computer?

Comment: Are these just user settings?

Comment: Yes, it's a logon script

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My suggestion is similar to inhabitant's..

Create a sub-OU just for that single computer, create a GPO in it and set it to loopback merge mode. Use security filtering on the GPO so that only `DumbGuy` have permissions to apply it. I don't see any reason for using two different GPO's.

**Mucho importante! Don't filter the "read" rights from the authenticated users, as the group policy subsystem needs to read the GPO before it applies to the user**

Comment: I've done this this morning and it worked well. Created a Sub-OU, put his computer in it, put the GPO on the OU and filtered it to his username. Perfecto.

Comment: +1 - Exactly how I'd do it, too.

Comment: P.S. Thanks for that last tip as well; I always forget that removing "Authenticated Users" from the security filtering removes their delegation permissions as well.

Answer (score 6):

I would look at [Group Policy Loopback Processing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231287) in conjunction with Security Filtering.
You can use the Group Policy loopback feature to apply Group Policy Objects (GPOs) that depend only on which computer the user logs on to.

[This is an example of how it can be implemented](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/windows-server-understand-user-group-policy-loopback-processing-mode.aspx).

Actually, how would I implement this:

Create two different GPO and assign them to DOMAIN\DumbGuysComputer$.

Configure first GPO with ***Loopback Processing*** set in Replace Mode and configure ***Security Filtering*** to apply only to *DOMAIN\DumbGuy* user.

Configure second GPO without Loopback Processing and configure Security Filtering to apply only to *DOMAIN\NiceReceptionist* users.

Answer (score 5):

I would probably just link the GPO to the OU that the user is in and use security filtering or WMI to make sure that it only applies to that one user, then wrap the whole script in a `if($ENV:computername -eq whatever){}` block.

Comment: This is very clever! Pauska's solution was a bit neater, but if I ever can't move the computer's OU I will do this.

Answer (score 0):

GPO apply to ether the user object, computer object or both objects in a OU and you can't make the GPO apply only to a computer object only if a certain user logs in to that computer or apply to a user object only if that user logs into a certain computer.

Comment: It would appear you can't do this with standard filtering, but there are workarounds for it

Answer (score 0):

I created a WMI filter that seems to work:

```
Select * from WIN32_OperatingSystem where NOT CSName="PCName"
```

You can test WMI queries in powershell using:

```
gwmi -Query 'Select * from WIN32_OperatingSystem...'
```